# AWK Using a Variable in an Equality Expression

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cygwin

A simplified version of my code looks like the following:

```
declare -a DMN=(" " "200" "190" "180")
NRL=3

runDHFiles()
{
awk 'NR>13 {if ($4==$DMN[$i]) print $1, $2, $3, $4;}' domain_all.dat >> ddh_domain_${DMN[$i]}.dat
}

for ((i = 1; i <= NRL; i++ )); do
   runDHFiles
done
```

I'm trying to loop over a large Excel file and copy the rows where the domain flag (in column 4) equals a certain number.

If I do this, it works fine:

```
if ($4==200)
```

If I do this, it doesn't work:

```
if ($4==$DMN[$i])
```

How can I access value from the array in my loop for the equality statement?

Thanks,

Cole

Answer (score 1):

One option is to pass the shell variable into `awk`, which avoids requoting:

```
awk 'NR>13 {if ($4==dmn) print $1, $2, $3, $4;}' dmn="${DMN[$i]}" domain_all.dat >> ddh_domain_${DMN[$i]}.dat
```

---

I'd be inclined to refactor your shell script, too, so that the variable is passed into your shell function:

```
declare -a DMN=(" " "200" "190" "180")
NRL=3

runDHFiles()
{
    local dmn="$1"
    awk 'NR>13 && $4==dmn {print $1, $2, $3, $4;}' dmn="$dmn" domain_all.dat >> "ddh_domain_${dmn}.dat"
}

for ((i=1; i<=NRL; i++ ))
do
   runDHFiles "${DMN[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your quoting to allow the bash array variable to be "seen", this would improve it:

```
awk 'NR>13 {if ($4=="'"$DMN[$i]"'") print $1, $2, $3, $4;}' domain_all.dat >> ddh_domain_${DMN[$i]}.dat
```

That is, temporarily end the single-quoted part (and use double-quotes to make it a string for `awk`).

Alternatively (some prefer it) would be to use the `-v` option of `awk` to declare a variable, and use *that* in the script:

```
awk -v value=DMN[$i] 'NR>13 {if ($4==value) print $1, $2, $3, $4;}' domain_all.dat >> ddh_domain_${DMN[$i]}.dat
```